# Ordered field with nested intervals axiom without Archimedean axiom

Tags: field-theory, ordered-fields

> Does an ordered field $F$ satisfying the Cauchy-Cantor axiom but not the Archimedean axiom exist?

Cauchy-Cantor axiom: Every system of nested intervals $I_1 \supset I_2 \supset \cdots \supset I_n \supset \cdots$ have a common point. Here, an interval $I$ is any set of the form $I= \{ x \in F \mid a \leqslant x \leqslant b\}$  for some $a\le b$ in $F$.

Archimedean axiom: For every $x,y \in F$ with $y>0$ there exists a unique $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ny \leqslant x < (n+1)y$.

Comment: Start post has been changed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! "does the nested interval property imply that an ordered field is Archimedean", - how can I prove that?

Comment: One can construct an example using formal Laurent series.  For a discussion of every conceivable related question, please see [this article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.4483.pdf) by James Propp.

Comment: "The nested interval property statement has the inclusions running the wrong way.", - my fault, I changed. Thanks for article!

Comment: In case my answer was ambiguous, the nested interval property does not imply the field is Archimedean.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I try to build example. But I have 2 more questions: 1) does exist field without nested intervals principe with Archimed princepe 2) without nested intervals and without Archimed?

Comment: I found that in your article, thanks!

Comment: The question seems clear enough to me.

Comment: I've voted to re-open and posted this request: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc/16317#16317

Comment: Thank you! But Andre Nicolas has answered me already, I think the topic is exhausted.

Comment: @AndréNicolas : The question is re-opened.  You should make your comment an answer.

Comment: @kp9r4d : Since the question is now re-opened, if André Nicolas makes his comment into an "answer", you should probably "accept" it.

Comment: About Archimedean without nested interval, it is simple, the rationals. And non-Archimedean no nested interval, can take field of rational functions over the rationals, usual ordering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An ordered field that satisfies the Nested Interval Property need not be Archimedean.

A very nice paper that answers all questions of this general character that one might ask, and more, is James Propp's [*Real Analysis in Reverse*.](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.4483.pdf)

For an early class of examples, please see the classic *Rings of Continuous Functions* (Gillman and Jerison).

There are also constructions based on ultrapowers of the reals.

Comment: In the paper you link, on p.13 it says "*Note however that the field of formal Laurent series is not a counterexample; although it satisfies the Shrinking Interval Property, it does not satisfy the Nested Interval Property*". So your answer cannot possibly be "the standard example".

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking of Cantor's version, which is shrinking interval, and is not the one OP uses.

Comment: For people too lazy to open the article, Propp's counterexample for this is the surreals, or if you want a field that's actually a set, the surreals created before day $\omega_1$.  A few others are given as references.  See page 13 of Propp.